# MySql include partition key in index?

Tags: mysql, index, index-tuning

Please look at the following Mysql table: http://pastebin.com/b0NDSbdz

I've partitioned the table by `sent_at` and I'm making sure that most of the queries pass `sent_at`. do I need to include `sent_at` in all of the indexes?

do you spot any potential redundant indexes?

when I do include the `sent_at` in the indexes, does it have to be the first field in the index declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple questions, multiple answers:

- No need to "spot" potential redundant indexes: use either [common_schema](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/redundant_keys.html) or [Percona Toolkit](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-duplicate-key-checker.html) to find such keys. But I've checked -- and no, there are no redundant keys.
- You do not have to use `sent_at` in the indexes
- If you do, it does not matter (partition-wise) where in the index.

But the one thing that is not told is how you query your table. Do you do an equality check on most fields and range-check on `sent_at`? In such case better have `sent_at` indexed last. If there is an equality check on `sent_in` or range check on same field, with little or no filtering on other columns, then have `sent_in` indexed by itself, or first in sequence. Right now you have 1 month of data in each partition; getting it indexed by time is not such a bad idea.